# “Some day/time” if “some” modifies and specifies a more particular day/time

Tags: usage, adverbs, phrases, nouns, relative-clauses

> The adverbs ***someday*** and ***sometime*** express future time
> indefinitely: *Let's meet **sometime** when your schedule permits*.
> The two-word forms are always used when *some* is an adjective
> modifying and specifying a more particular day or time: *Come **some
> day** soon. Choose **some day** that is not so busy*.
>
> https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=S5608500

*Sometime* https://oed.com/oed2/00230637

Why is *some day **that is not so busy*** a "more particular" day but *sometime **when your schedule permits*** is not a "more particular" time, when both include similar relative clauses?

Comment: This is a cross-posting from ELU. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/569842/some-day-time-if-some-modifies-and-specifies-a-more-particular-day-time

Answer (score 1):

You are laying too much stress on the distinction between the one- and two-word forms here.

> sometime when your schedule permits

and

> some time when your schedule permits

have **exactly** the same meaning.

It is true that unqualified "someday" and 'sometime" indicate an indefinite future time. It is also true that when qualified  the two word forms are most often used:

> Let's meet **some day** next week

not

> Let's meet **someday** next week.

But the qualification is more important than the space between words. If a qualification is used with the one-word form, the qualification is what matters.

Both

> - some day that is not so busy
> - sometime when your schedule permits

are rather vague. In neither case is the proposed future event limited to a a specific period such as "next week". Indeed neither seems to amount to a definite promise, depending on other context. But one is not more definite than the other.

**Response to comment:**

It is quite true that the dictionary definitions of "[sometime](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/sometime)" and "[someday](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/someday)" indicate an indefinite future time. It might be arguably an error to use the one word forms with qualifications.  But a phrase such as "sometime when your schedule permits" is still quite indefinite. In any case fluent speakers and writers do use these phrases in this sort of way, and there is not normally any **intended** difference of meaning when the one-word form is used. Note that in speech there is no difference at all, only in writing.

**Further response**

It is true that "sometime", unlike "someday", can also refer to the past. I am not sure how that came to be so, at the moment that is just what the words mean. But none of the examples given seem to refer to the past in any way, so that difference does not seem relevant to these uses.

Comment: (adv.) at some indefinite time: _he arrived **sometime** LAST WEEK_. https://www.wordreference.com/definition/sometime

Comment: @GJC  See my "response to comment" section just added to my answer.

Comment: I meant _sometime_, unlike _someday_,, can also refer to the past

Comment: So can [***some day***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22some+day+last+week%22) refer to the past, as per many of the matching written instances in that link. Also note that although the single-word form ***someday*** has been steadily gaining traction in the US since WW2, it's only very recently become the dominant orthography in the UK.